# pubspec.yaml error Expected a key while parsing a block mapping

Tags: flutter

This is my pubspec.yaml:
name: flutter_application_1_dropdownmenu
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:

sdk: ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
bloc: ^8.1.0
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_bloc: ^8.1.1

dev_dependencies:
bloc_test: ^9.0.0
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
mocktail: ^1.0.0

flutter:

uses-material-design: true

And the error is:
[image]

I try to do:
flutter pub get
And it gives the error I already put.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax Issue.
Make sure the file follows the syntax structure below

```
name: <project name>
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: none

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ^3.3.0

dependencies:
  flutter:       # Required for every Flutter project
    sdk: flutter # Required for every Flutter project
  flutter_localizations: # Required to enable localization
    sdk: flutter         # Required to enable localization

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6 # Only required if you use Cupertino (iOS style) icons

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter # Required for a Flutter project that includes tests

  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1 # Contains a set of recommended lints for Flutter code

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true # Required if you use the Material icon font

  generate: true # Enables generation of localized strings from arb files

  assets:  # Lists assets, such as image files
    - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
    - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  fonts:              # Required if your app uses custom fonts
    - family: Schyler
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
    - family: Trajan Pro
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
        - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```